# How do I find the location of the Python stdout file object?

Tags: python

In Python I know that the standard output stream is available as the **stdout** file object in the built-in sys module but I'm confused: first, I'm not able to locate the *sys* module in the way I do with any other module (`modulename.__file__`); secondond, I don't know how to locate the stdout file objects.

Comment: built-in => no `__file__` attribute. what do you mean by "unable to locate stdout objects"? which information do you need from them?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre "unable" means that I don't know how to do locate it. I would like to see it.

Comment: `sys.stdout` it is. What more do you need?

Comment: is `stdout` a name inside the `sys` module? Where I can find the sys module? How can I read the line of code inside `sys` where stdout is defined?

Comment: this is a built-in, probably not coded in python but directly in C !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stdout` is defined in the `sys` module.  Assuming you are using the C implementation, download the source code (3.6) and look in `Python/sysmodule.c`.  However, `stdout` itself is assigned from `PyId_stdout` which is defined in `Python/pylifecycle.c` in the function `initstdio`:

```
/* Set sys.stdout */
fd = fileno(stdout);
std = create_stdio(iomod, fd, 1, "<stdout>", encoding, errors);
if (std == NULL)
    goto error;
PySys_SetObject("__stdout__", std);
_PySys_SetObjectId(&PyId_stdout, std);
Py_DECREF(std);
```

As you can see, it is derived from the `stdio` C runtime library.  Also, `__stdout__` is created at the same time, and this is meant to be a fall-back to recover `stdout` if you reassign it.

The function `create_stdio` in the same source file also contains further details, like buffering, newlines, and encoding.